# MVC4 Dynamic DateTime Value in Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I am trying to generate a dynamic warranty end date by calculation and I am getting nowhere with intelisense.  Any help will be appreciated.

```
   public int WarrantyMonths {get;set;}
   public DateTime DateIn{get;set;}   
   public DateTime? WarrantyEnd
    {
        get { return DateTime.AddMonths(this.DateIn((this.WarrantyMonths))); }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx) on how to use a function if you don't understand it. What you probably want is:

```
get { return DateIn.AddMonths(WarrantyMonths); }
```

Comment: I made the DateIn Nullable and that was the problem So your solution works Thanks very much.